# is not assignable to parameter of type [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have problem in react
I wrote enum type

enum.ts

```
export enum DivingType {
  FreeDiving = "FreeDiving",
  ScubaDiving = "ScubaDiving",
}
```

and my home screen has graphql hooks

home.tsx

```
import { DivingType } from "..."

export const Home = () => {
  const [divingType, setDivingType] = useState<DivingType>(DivingType.FreeDiving)
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)

  useMatchingList(divingType, pageNumber)
  
  // --------------------[ Return ]--------------------
  return ...
```

useMatchingList.tsx

```
interface IUseMatchingListProps {
  divingType: DivingType
  pageNumber: number
}
export const useMatchingList: React.FC<IUseMatchingListProps> = ({
  divingType,
 ,
}) => {...}
```

and I have

```
Argument of type 'import("...").DivingType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropsWithChildren<IUseMatchingListProps>'

useMatchingList(divingType, pageNumber)
       |            ^
```

what is the matter ?
please help me !

Comment: `useMatchingList` looks like a hook, but it's typed like a component? Which is it?

Comment: oh .. should I remove React.FC<IUseMatchingListProps> in hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FC` in `React.FC` means "Functional Component". And a hook is not a component. A custom hook is just a function that calls other hooks. So it takes arguments just like any function would.

That means your hooks should look more like this:

```
export const useMatchingList = (divingType: DivingType, pageNumber: number) => {
  // my hook implementation
}
```

[Working typesafe example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXSAHpFhwkAO3zMAIsABuwEQHMAKgE8wVHFzhwAYuyRTZCuAF44AIl1J9MufLOZNcEmnwAjFAdsnzztx5sK9lzUPLwC0PBoECKE8ERIALIUaAAWtgAywLHeABQAJgFKqkgAXHCeCipq2GAo8kgAcuKuSFBlYiAtUACUJgB8uI4A9ENwIMpwKRAQANZwoGAANkggouQwwNHBPPyCkdHZABJMVKY5vcYDGlpRMfAA2gWGRdVwxDAVL0gAut7xZBQkAAeT5VJB9HKg4oAOks1me3Uct2y91q9SanVa2HeAAU6o1mq1fqZ-uskDkAIyIxzxJIwVIZLIwfKFME1fEYrqIrTDUYAWgFgqFwuF90QSBg+CgIjg3xF8vljnYkulcCBfSBQz6PBCXCAA)